# Adding labels to a ggplot2 bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I love the simplicity of making relative frequency bar charts for categorical data in ggplot2, but I have the difficulty of adding the percentage values as labels on top of them. Does anybody have a simple solution for this?

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(responses=c(rep("A",5),
                             rep("B",15),
                             rep("C", 25)))
ggplot(df, aes(responses))+
  geom_bar(aes(y=..prop..*100, group=1))+
  geom_text(aes(label=..prop.., group=1))
```

Comment: Try with `geom_text(aes(y=..prop.. * 100, label=..prop.., group=1), stat = "count", vjust = 0, nudge_y = 1)`

Comment: Thanks!  if you could post this as solution, I would gratefully accept it :)
`geom_text(aes(y=..prop.. * 100, label=round(..prop..*100,1), group=1), stat = "count", vjust = -0.5)`
The only thing I don;'t get is WHY i do need `stat="count"`?

Comment: You can also use `scales::percent` to format the percentages, e.g. `ggplot(df, aes(responses))+geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.. * 100, group = 1)) +geom_text(aes(y = ..prop.. * 100, label = scales::percent(..prop..), group = 1),stat = "count", vjust = 0, nudge_y = 1)`

Comment: `prop` is a variable computed by `stat_count`. For geom_bar the stats layer is `stat_count` by default. However, variables computed by a stat are only available "locally" in the geom. Hence, to make prop available from within `geom_text` you have to compute it again by adding stat = "count" as for geom_text the default stat is stat_identity.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more straightforward to plot the calculated proportion using `geom_col()`.

```
df <- data.frame(responses=c(rep("A",5),
                             rep("B",15),
                             rep("C", 25)))

df1 <-  df %>% 
  count(responses) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n))

ggplot(df1, aes(responses, prop)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_label(aes(label = scales::percent(prop)))
```